# Как получить последнее сообщение?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, pyrogram

Мне нужно получить текст последнего сообщения из чата. Библиотека pyrogram

Comment: как последнее сообщение? любое сообщение это последнее, очень странный вопрос, уточните пожалуйста, что конкретно вы пытаетесь сделать, и что вы пытались сделать.

Answer (score 0):

```
async def get_last_message():
    # по аналогу шаблона из документации
    async for message in app.get_chat_history(chat_id, limit=1, offset_id=-1):
        print(message.text)
```

Ну и где-то в коде вызвать эту функцию:

```
await get_last_message()
```

Ссылка на пример в документации: https://docs.pyrogram.org/start/examples/get_chat_history